# Java reflection to change parameter?

Tags: java, reference, out, ref

I'm writing a method in Java that I want to simulate references.. Since java doesn't have the out keyword like in C# and doesn't have References/Pointers like in C++, I want to know if I can use reflection to simulate it.

An example would be:

```
public static boolean ChangeValue(Object Input, Object Output) {
    //Use some reflection here to change the value of Output?
    return true;
}
```

then in main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int I = 0;
    ChangeValue(I, I);
    System.out.println(I);
}
```

So.. Can I use reflection to change the value of any parameter passed to my ChangeValue method? I do not want to return Composite objects..

Comment: If you insist on using this pattern, you're probably better off implementing a simple `Out<T>` container class.

Comment: ^Yes it does compile.. You can try it and see.. Object is a polymorphic class.. Anything can be passed as Object including primitives.

Comment: Right you are, I stand corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is pass-by-reference-value, meaning that if you pass an Object to a method and modify it, the object "outside" of the method will be modified as well (because the Object is simply a reference). An example of this is calling [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29) on an array.

However, this is not the case for primitives (like `int`), in which case Java is pass-by-value, so your example with `int I` wouldn't work.  In order to modify the value of `int I`, you should return an `int` from your method, and set it to `I` accordingly.

This means that reflection *is not* necessary in order to modify the object's value from within the `ChangeValue` method; anything done to the object within the method, will in effect, modify the object in the scope of the `main` method.

Comment: :S I tried passing Integer and changing the value. It does not affect anything in main.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Correct, and nothing in this answer implies that it would.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames In the second paragraph of my answer, I explain how primitives (like `int`) are not pass-by-reference-value.  You should instead return a value and set it to `I` (as my answer explains).

Comment: "anything done to the object within the method, will in effect, modify the object in the scope of the main method." I think read this wrong.
Integer is a class and int is a primitive type.

Comment: "Object" is the key word there; otherwise, you read it correctly.  Primitives (`int`, `long`, `double`, `char`, `boolean`, etc) **are not** objects, and are passed by value rather than by reference value.

Comment: Yes but things such as String and Integer and Double are not primitive :S I thought Box types are not primitive?

Comment: Strings are immutable, and while box types are technically objects, they are still passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.

You can change properties of objects you pass to a method, but you cannot change what the calling code's parameter references–just properties of what it references.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames And I'm saying you can't; you cannot change what the calling code references, only properties of what it references, from the called method. It's the same thing with an int; you cannot change the value of a variable in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static boolean changeValue(ArrayList<String> input, ArrayList<String> output) {
        //this changes a property on output, but does not change the reference to output
        output.addAll(input);


        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        list1.add("Foo");

        System.out.println("List 2: " + list2);
        System.out.println("List 2 size:" + list2.size());

        changeValue(list1, list2);

        System.out.println("List 2: " + list2);    
        System.out.println("List 2 size:" + list2.size());
    }
```

Would print...

List 2: ArrayList@0x23409

List 2 size: 0

List 2: ArrayList@0x23409

List 2 size: 1

Comment: +1 I like this. I will just give up and make a class with type and modify it :( Was really hoping there was a way to just do it without work arounds..